# jquery ajax loading div not working in IE & Chrome

Tags: ajax, jquery, loading

This has been asked many many times. But none of the solutions are working for me in IE and Chrome.

I basically want to show a loading image while ajax call is being made.

Following is what I'm trying.

```
function ws(){
    showL();
    var res=$.ajax({url:'webservice.asp?service=LoadingTestSRV',async:false,cache:false}).responseText;
    $('#dv').html(res);
    hideL();
    $('#complete').html('Done');
}
function showL()
{
    $('#loading').show();
}
function hideL()
{
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

Following is the HTML

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
  <tr><td>
        <input type="button" value="ckick" id="btn" onClick="ws();">
        <input type="button" value="clear" onClick="$('#dv,#complete').html('');">
    </td><td>
        <div id="dv"></div>
    </td></tr><tr>
    <td>Here<div id="loading" style="display:none" >Loading.................</div></td>
    <td>final<div id="complete"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

After above js, I tried

- ajaxStart and ajaxStop
- $.ajaxSetup
- $.ajax({...}).done(hideL)

**All the js codes I tried are working in Firefox but none of them are working in IE and Chrome.**
In Firefox, the code works as expected. Loading div gets shown, ajax is called, loading div gets hidden. This is exactly what I'm expecting.
In IE & Chrome, loading div doesn't show up. Maybe It's getting shown and hidden very fast after or before ajax call.

Please let me know what can be done to make the code work in IE & Chrome.

There has to be some workaround as I've seen other sites show loading div. Or maybe I'm doing something stupid.

Once the code is working in all browsers. I want to make a generic function (like a jQuery plugin) to show a loading div when ajax is being called.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is not working? Is it showing but not hiding ors it not showing at all? Could `async:false` be the issue here?

Comment: I've updated the post above. Loading div is not showing up in IE & Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
This will ensure that ur DIV is hidden after the ajax call completes

```
    function ws() {
        showL();
         var res ="";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'webservice.asp?service=LoadingTestSRV',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                res=data;
                $('#dv').html(res);
                hideL();
                $('#complete').html('Done');

            }
        });

    }

    function showL() {
        $('#loading').show();
    }

    function hideL() {
        $('#loading').hide();
    }​
```

Comment: This code is behaving in the same way in Chrome. It's not showing the loading div.

Comment: @Yogesh Sawant try making async:true

Comment: async:true did the same :(

Comment: hmm.. its not showing the DIV at all? lets see if we can debug this, can u remobe everythign from ws() except the showL() call and see if the DIV shows then?

Comment: And can u check the chrome network XHR inspector to check if the AJAX call is faling?

Comment: I'm sorry! using async:true worked. Thanks a lot man. will try this in my earlier code

Comment: @YogeshSawant if it helped, please take the time and "accept" the answer.. I will update it to use async:true

Comment: I was facing the same problem and I have added parameters mentioned above and its working for me !! thanks @sajan Sarkar

Answer (score 3):

This form has worked for me previously: (I put in the slow so you could see it if it is fast)

```
$('#loading').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show("slow");
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

Test example of this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/xgFkw/

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way try if it helps..

```
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loadingDiv').show();
            $('#accordion').hide()
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loadingDiv').hide();
            $('#accordion').show();
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: 
        data: shallowEncodedData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your ajax call. Remove the `async:false` from ajax call and it will work even in IE8/9 and Chrome. For other Lost-souls, please do the above changes and try again.

Comment: I had 3 lines of code.

 $("#id").text("Proccesing ...");

$("#id").show(); 

alert($("#id").text()); ..

It alerts me Proccessing but why don't it show the div? 
It works fine when async:true but div does not show up when async:false. 
??

Answer (score 1):

simple just Add async=true in ajax function. It will work in chrome

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this issue in Chrome, use a timeout on the AJAX call of one millisecond.

E.g.

```
$("#mySpinningLoader").show();

var t = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: rootPath + controllerNAction,
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(lightweightObject),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#mySpinningLoader").hide();
        }
    });
}, 1);
```

Comment: Also, had to wrap my loading image with a setTimeout to get this to work.

var t1 = setTimeout(function () {
document.getElementById("divLoading").style.display = "";
    }, 1);